# Subgroups of the additive groups of integrers mod n

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently working in group theory , following Hungerford's algebra chapter 1, and I was seeing the subgroups of the integers mod n under addition in an example in the section 1.2 and a question popped up in my head:

Why doesn't the group $\mathbb{Z}_N$ contain all of the other groups $\mathbb{Z}_{n<N}$? In this example we have to see that $\{0,3\}$ and $\{0, 2,4\}$ are subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ I did they cayley table and I proved that they indeed are subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ but why isn't $\{0,1,2\}$ which is $\mathbb{Z}_3$ a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_5$, for example?

I'd like to think, for example, that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ contains $\mathbb{Z}_2$,$\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ but I know this is not correct and I'd like to know why this is not the case.

Comment: The short answer to this is that the elements of $\mathbb Z_n$ are different from that of $\mathbb Z_m$ for different $m,n$.

Comment: Is $3+4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ the same as $3+4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$?  _(This is a rhetorical question.)_

Comment: You seem to be confusing what elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ and $\Bbb Z_N$ are, for $n\ne N$: $\Bbb Z_3$ is not a subset of $\Bbb Z_5$, nor can it be *isomorphic to a subgroup* of $\Bbb Z_5$ because Lagrange's theorem prevents it, as $3\nmid 5$.

Answer (score 3):

As much as it’s true that not all numbers strictly less than $n$ divide $n$, $Z_n$ doesn’t contain every $Z_i$ for every suitable $i<n$. Maybe it would be nice but it doesn’t work like that because of the structure of cyclic groups (look up Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups).

Using this theorem, a better way to visualize the cyclic groups is to think of them as a subgroup lattice (look this up too). This is because there’s a unique subgroup of order $d$ for every $d|n$ and there are no other subgroups besides these. Thus, there are a finite number of subgroups of $Z_n$ that we may map out in this manner.

This is an important theme in mathematics - namely that we can sometimes break up structures into “smaller” substructures in a manner mimicking how we may break up integers into products of primes.

Answer (score 1):

The fact $\Bbb Z_N\cap\Bbb Z_n=\emptyset$ for every $n\ne N$ would suffice to negatively answer your question, as such things as "$\Bbb Z_n\le \Bbb Z_N$" wouldn't thence even make sense (as $\Bbb Z_n$ is not a subset of $\Bbb Z_N$). But probably you meant whether an embedding $\Bbb Z_n\hookrightarrow\Bbb Z_N$ does exist for every $n\le N$, namely whether $\Bbb Z_N$ contains an *isomorphic copy* of $\Bbb Z_n$ for every $n\le N$. A necessary condition for this to hold, is that $n\mid N$ (Lagrange's theorem), so that -for example- $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$ can embed into $\Bbb Z_6$ (and they actually do), while $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_5$ don't.

Answer (score 0):

because  for example $2+2 = 4$ is not in $A = \{0,1,2\}\subset \mathbb{Z}_5$, and hence, $A$ it is not stable by addition therefore it is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.